# Getting error message for chrome driver script in selenium 3

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, driver

I have downloaded selenium 3 jars and also have installed chrome driver.
The following is the code - 
package samplewebchrome;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class googlewindows {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String baseUrl = "http;//www.goggle.com";

    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium3\\bin\\samplewebchrome\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

}

and the error message is as follows:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Selenium important files\chromedriver
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at samplewebchrome.googlewindows.main(googlewindows.java:18)

I am struggling with this issue from today morning. It would be of great help if someone tries to give me a solution over this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check whether the chrome driver is available in the specified location?

Comment: Can you share the exact version of chrome browser , chrome driver , selenium version , and your OS ?

Comment: In addition to setting the correct location to the executable, add the line `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();` followed by `driver = new ChromeDriver(options)`.

Comment: @cruisepandey - chrome browser = Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit),  chrome driver = ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 ,  selenium version = 3.13.0  and OS =Windows 10  64 bit

Comment: Your sample code says `C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium3\\bin\\samplewebchrome\\chromedriver.exe` but the error says `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Selenium important files\chromedriver`. These do not match! Could you post [mcve] how exactly you are running this?

Comment: @SiKing, yes i am confused over where to keep the chrome driver exe. hence i tried keeping the chrome driver exe @   C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Selenium important files\chromedriver and also @  C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium3\\bin\\samplewebchrome\\chromedriver.exe. Inspite of this i am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

To verify chrome driver is compatible with your current chrome & selenium version, do the following:

Keep downloaded chrome driver at **System32** if you are on Windows OS & **/usr/local/bin** if you are on Mac OSX

1. Run the Selenium Standalone server by this command: java -jar
   selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
2. Open this url in chrome browser: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
3. Create Session and Select Chrome browser

If browser starts then there is no issue with the compatibility of chrome driver with Chrome & Selenium version.

Answer (score 0):

put `chromedriver.exe` at
`C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium3\\bin\\samplewebchrome\\`
as you are setting property as

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium3\\bin\\samplewebchrome\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Also make sure your chrome browser version and chromedriver are compatible,if you are using latest chrome browser then the latest `chromedriver.exe` can be downloaded from `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html`

Comment: Done with this now chrome brrowser is getting opened but throwing new error now. will post it as a new question.